# how to print 60*48 mm size paper in java

Tags: java, printing, barcode, tsc

I am trying to print 60*48 mm size paper usnig tsc printer.
I have given the size but it is not working properly.

```
   double paperWidthInInch =2.36;// 
   double paperHeightInInch =1.88;//5.6
   PrinterJob prnJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
   //prnJob.setCopies(2);
   PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
   Paper p = new Paper();
   p.setSize(paperWidthInInch*72, paperHeightInInch*72);
   p.setImageableArea(0, 0, (paperWidthInInch*72d)+100, (paperHeightInInch*72d)+100);
```

i am using tsc barcode printer. it contain product details and barcode image.
while printing it will print extra paper and mismatch scale size.